# Separar palavras digitadas dentro de um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um `input`, onde o usuário digita o seu nome completo a partir do seguinte código:

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" title="fullname" maxlength="255" class="input-text fullname onestep" placeholder="Escreva o nome completo" onchange="saveNomeSobrenome($j(this).val())" />
```

Por meio da função `saveNomeSobrenome()`, eu consigo separar somente a última palavra digitada pelo usuário que vou salvar como sobrenome, porém precisava separar o "resto" que ele digitou para salvar como nome. Uma dificuldade que também estou é em transformar essa função `javascript` em `jQuery`.

**Código da função:**

```
function saveNomeSobrenome(string){ 
     var frase = string;
     var palavras = frase.split(" ");
     tamanho = palavras.length;
     sobrenome = palavras[tamanho-1];
     console.log(sobrenome);
}
```

Comment: Por que você não coloca logo dois input para nome e sobrenome? João Pedro da Silva por exemplo ficaria errado. O nome do cara não é "João Pedro da". Melhor pedir o nome ao usuário do que ficar tentando adivinhar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode transformar o JS para um evento direto no JQuery com:

```
$("#fullname").change(function(){ 
     var palavras = $(this).val().split(" ");
     tamanho = palavras.length;
     sobrenome = palavras[tamanho-1];
     console.log(sobrenome);
});
```

Assim não precisa criar uma função e atribuir a um evento no html.

Você deve usar o método split :

```
'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' '); // Isso retorna ["Paul", "Steve", "Panakkal"]
```

Você pode usá-lo desta maneira:

```
'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' '); // Retorna "Paul Steve"
'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' '); // Retorna "Panakkal"
```

Então, em comum:

```
var primeiroNome = nomeCompleto.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
var Sobrenome = nomeCompleto.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 7):

Tenta o código abaixo. Testado no fiddle.
Tentei deixar o mais parecido com o seu código mas dá para reduzir para 2 linhas;

Copie o código do input também.

```
  <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" title="fullname" maxlength="255" class="input-text fullname onestep" placeholder="Escreva o nome completo" onchange="saveNomeSobrenome(this.value);" />
<script>
function saveNomeSobrenome(str){ 
     var frase = str;
     var palavras = frase.split(" ");
     tamanho = palavras.length;
     sobrenome = palavras[palavras.length - 1];
     alert(sobrenome);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Primeira coisa que você precisa saber é que **não existe** conversão JavaScript para jQuery, **jQuery é JavaScript**, então tudo o que você escrever em jQuery var "virar código JavaScript puro".

O que você pode fazer é adaptar seu código para usar as funções do jQuery, pra seguir algum padrão determinado pelo projeto ou por qualquer outro motivo.

Uma das maneiras de se fazer o que é pedido na pergunta, é usando o método `splice()` do *array*.

Fazendo um `splice(-1, 1)`, o último elemento do *array* será removido e retornado. Isso fará com que o *array* original contenha exatamente as palavras que você precisa (o resto do nome).

No exemplo eu também removi o evento e usei um botão para disparar a função, isso porque fica mais fácil de testar. Se você quiser trocar o botão de volta para o evento `change` basta alterar esta linha

```
$('#bt').on('click', saveNomeSobrenome);
```

para

```
$('#fullname').on('change', saveNomeSobrenome);
```

```js
$('#bt').on('click', saveNomeSobrenome);

function saveNomeSobrenome(){ 
  var input = $('#fullname').val();
  
  const palavras = input.split(" ");
  sobrenome = palavras.splice(-1, 1).join('');
  const resto = palavras.join(' ');
  
  console.log(`Sobrenome: ${sobrenome} — Resto do nome: ${resto}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" title="fullname" maxlength="255" class="input-text fullname onestep" placeholder="Escreva o nome completo" />

<button id="bt"> Salvar </button>
```